# I need to sort the names based on Regex pattern, how can i do?

Tags: java, regex, sorting

I need to sort the names. and these names some times stats with number and how can i make to sort on the number if name has and if doesn't.At present i am sorting only alphabets.

```
Ex: 3.Animal
    1.Box
    4.Monkey
    2.Tiger
```

But i need to display above as follows.

```
1.Box
2.Tiger
3.Animal
4.Monkey
```

Do I need regular expression, and if yes what RE do I need?

if no how do i procceed in java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching, not sorting. You could use a RE to parse a string, but that's another matter, not directly related to the sorting issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex certainly seems like it would be a reasonable first step. Do you know about [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)? It defines a method `int compare(T one, T two)` which has the usual int-as-comparison-result semantics. Once you have an instance of `Comparator`, you can pass it to sorting methods, such as `Collections.sort`.

So, one approach would be to write a `Comparator<String>` whose `compare` method uses a regex to extract the two Strings' number portions, and then does a numerical comparison. The problem with this is that you'll be doing that parsing each time you look at each String, which could get expensive.

An alternative would be to create a `TreeMap<Integer,String>`, and insert key-value pairs where the key is the parsed int and the value is the original String. Then you can just iterate over the value set, and they'll come out in key order. That would probably be the approach I'd take.

**EDIT** yytg brings up a good point, which is that for such a simple parse, you'd be just as good splitting on `"\\."` (with a limit of 2) and parsing the lefthand side. You could also use `String.indexOf` to find the dot and then `String.substring` to get the portion of the String to the left of the dot.

Comment: You should also consider what happens when there's a collision. For instance, if you have inputs `1.Box`, `2.Tiger`, `1.Animal`. If you use the `Collections.sort` approach, the like-numbered strings will be grouped together, and in the same order they appeared originally (it's a stable sort). You can also sort them alphabetically iff the numbers are the same in the Comparator. In the `TreeMap` approach, the second string you see would kick out the first one, so you'd lose values. A `TreeMap<Integer,List<String>>` would fix that, at the cost of a tad extra complexity and object allocation.

Answer (score 1):

The Comparator guy is correct, MalTec is close, but would tip over at "11.Liger" or nulls anywhere.  THE UBER STRING SORTER IS...

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    List<String> theStrings = Arrays.asList( new String[] {
            "3.Animal",
            "1.Box",
            "4.Monkey",
            "2.Tiger",
            "11.Panzerkampfwagen",
            null,
            null,
            "127.0.0.1" } );
    Collections.sort( theStrings, new Comparator<String>() {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "(\\d+).*" );

        @Override
        public int compare( String s1, String s2 ) {
            if ( s1 == null && s2 == null ) {
                return 0;
            } else if ( s1 != null && s2 == null ) {
                return -1;
            } else if ( s1 == null && s2 != null ) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                Matcher s1Matcher = pattern.matcher( s1 );
                Matcher s2Matcher = pattern.matcher( s2 );
                if ( !s1Matcher.matches() && !s2Matcher.matches() ) {
                    return s1.compareTo( s2 );
                } else if ( s1Matcher.matches() && !s2Matcher.matches() ) {
                    return -1;
                } else if ( !s1Matcher.matches() && s2Matcher.matches() ) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    int i1 = Integer.parseInt( s1Matcher.group( 1 ) );
                    int i2 = Integer.parseInt( s2Matcher.group( 1 ) );
                    return i1 - i2;
                }
            }
        }

    } );
    System.out.println( theStrings );
}
```

output is

```
[1.Box, 2.Tiger, 3.Animal, 4.Monkey, 11.Panzerkampfwagen, 127.0.0.1, null, null]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a custom 'Comparator' - look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) - no need for regex - you can split the string by the '.' and then take the left side and convert it to a number

Answer (score 0):

if u have . form,at fixed for all the records, following code should work for u.. no need for regex.. And yeah hope this is not some tutorial u asked here

```
String[] source={"3.Animal","1.Box","4.Monkey","2.Tiger"};


Arrays.sort(source, new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

      // to the start of the other, or else throwing an exception)
       if ((s1.indexOf('.') == -1) || (s2.indexOf('.') == -1)) { // both or neither
                return 0;
        }
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
   }
});


for(int i=0;i<source.length;i++){
    System.out.println("String - "+i+" : "+source[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Odaiah :-) if it worked upvote and/or accept the answer so that others having similar issue can use this answer.